# I would like to concatentate a column of results

Tags: .net

I use a query that gives me a list of locomotives in a particular shed on a given day. Unfortunately the output is not in the format I would like.

Currently it is:

```
Heaton

B9

1469
1475

Immingham

B3

1497
1498

J94

8006
8009
8012
8013
```

Heaton & Immingham are sheds

B3, B9 & J94 are classes of locos

I would like:

```
Heaton

B9  1469, 1475

Immingham

B3   1497, 1498

J94 8006, 8009, 8012, 8013
```

To give some idea of the size the database will be when completed there will be approx 11500 locos, 120 sheds and 100 Classes.

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having problems doing completing what you tried? You say you use a query, what are you querying SQL? can you please show us your query.

Comment: Hi the question does not appear quite how I typed it

Comment: If the text is not showing up correctly wrap the text in `<pre></pre>` tags or highlight the text and press the `{ }` button above the text editor window if the text is code.

Comment: Hi the question does not appear quite how I typed i, currently the loco numbers are in column format i.e. one above the other

Comment: Please show us how you are pulling the data out, include the code that does it.